# R For Loops Column Means

Tags: r

**Updated based on responses. Added reproducible data. Unfortunately, I have to do a For Loop within a For Loop.**

I need to do a for loop within a for loop to determine the column means. The outer for loop is to determine which columns are numeric. The inner for loop calculates the means for each column (while excluding NAs). I think I have the outer loop down. I just can't seem to figure out how to do the inner loop with the approach I'm taking. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
a <- c('Ned', 'Rod', 'Todd')
b <- c(60, 10, 8)
c <- c(190, 80, 60)
Flanders <- data.frame(Name=a, Age=b, Weight=c)

numericvars <- NULL
for (m in names(Flanders)){
  if(class(Flanders[,m]) == 'integer' | class(Flanders[,m]) == 'numeric'){
    numericvars[m] <- mean(Flanders[,m],na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Comment: How about `colMeans(mydata[sapply(mydata, is.numeric)])`.  Checking for numeric will suffice, because integer is also numeric.

Comment: I have to do a for loop within a for loop and compare that (inefficient) method to other methods.

Comment: Any *reproducible data* is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Added reproducible data. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some very strange but working (and does work) function using a loop within a loop. Hopefully it can be of some help. Note that the integer is something like a subclass of numeric.

```
numericvars <- NULL
flanders.mean <- NULL
for (m in names(Flanders)){
  if(is.numeric(Flanders[, m])){
    numericvars <- c(numericvars, m)
  }
  for (k in numericvars) {
    flanders.mean[m] <- sum(Flanders[, m])/nrow(Flanders)
  }
}

flanders.mean 
   Age Weight 
    26    110
```

Answer (score 2):

There are other tools built for this already, if you are willing to go a different route. In particular, `summarise_if` from `dplyr` may be useful to you (using the builtin `iris` data, since no reproducible data was included:

```
summarise_if(iris, is.numeric, mean)
```

returns

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333
```

It has the added version of playing nicely with `group_by` making it flexible for other needs. For example:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)
```

returns

```
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
      <fctr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

If you really must use the `for` loop, this should do it:

```
numericvars <- NULL
for (m in names(iris)){
  if(class(iris[,m]) == 'integer' | class(iris[,m]) == 'numeric'){
    numericvars[m] <- mean(iris[,m], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
```

generates a vector `numericvars` containing:

```
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
    5.843333     3.057333     3.758000     1.199333
```

Or, you can go with one of the `apply`'s and streamline your code a bit. Here, it loops through each column, checks if it is numeric (which I believe shows TRUE for integers as well), and returns the mean if it is and NA if not. You can then remove the NA's if you really don't want them in your result:

```
sapply(iris, function(x){
  if(is.numeric(x)){
    mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  } else{
    NA
  }
})
```

returns

```
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
    5.843333     3.057333     3.758000     1.199333           NA
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm supposed to do a for loop within a for loop. But I think the solution you gave will help me create that.

Answer (score 0):

I like the `dplyr` solution by Mark but in case you want a Base R solution I thought I would provide one.

You can do this using `colMeans` and `sapply` by abusing the fact that a data frame is a list of vectors.

```
colMeans(mydata[sapply(mydata,function(x) inherits(x,"numeric") | 
         inherits(x,"integer"))])
```

The

```
sapply(mydata,function(x) inherits(x,"numeric") | 
         inherits(x,"integer"))
```

returns a vector of logicals based on whether or not the column `inherits` either the class `numeric` or `integer`. I would suggest that `inherits` is better than `==` at dealing with variables in your data frame that have more than a single class attribute.

I have then used the resultant vector of logicals to keep the relevant subset of `mydata` and used `colMeans` for fast computation of each columns mean.

Example using data `diamonds` from `ggplot2`

```
data(diamonds,package = "ggplot2")
mydata = diamonds
colMeans(mydata[sapply(mydata,function(x) inherits(x,"numeric") | 
         inherits(x,"integer"))])
##     carat        depth        table        price            x 
##   0.7979397   61.7494049   57.4571839 3932.7997219    5.7311572 
##           y            z 
##   5.7345260    3.5387338
```

Edit:

It seems `is.numeric` is a much nicer way to check which does indeed return `TRUE` for integers as the other answer suggests, so

```
colMeans(mydata[sapply(mydata,is.numeric)])
```

does the same as the above. In addition `colMeans` has the `na.rm` argument too.

Further Edit:

Just seen @RichScriven's comment, which must have appeared while I was typing this up so credit due there too.

Comment: It's for an assignment where I have to use for loops and compare the run time against other methods. Thanks