# How to I find the mean of all numeric columns in r, with one non-numeric one?

Tags: r, csv

I have data in R exported from a csv. The first column contains the date, and the other 20 columns contain exchange rates in 20 different countries. How do I find the mean of the exchange rate in each country? I used `sapply` for the data but that did not work as the first column, the date, is not numeric.

I then tried deleting the date column using `ExRate$date<-NULL` then using `sapply(ExRate,mean)`. I got the same error as above.

Please direct me on how I should go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R For Loops Column Means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596947/r-for-loops-column-means)

Answer (score 4):

We can use `summarise_if`

```
library(dplyr)
ExRate %>%
       summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)
```

---

As a reproducible example

```
data(iris)
iris %>%
    summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just subset off the first date column:

```
ex_means <- sapply(ExRate[, 2:21], mean)
```

If you are unsure what the position of the date column is, then you could also phrase the above as using all columns *except* for the date column:

```
ex_means <- sapply(ExRate[, -which(names(ExRate) == "date")])
```

Comment: `sapply(ExRate[, -1], mean)` would probably be simpler in the first instance.